# Google colabを使って並列化計算の状況について

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-multiprocessing

現在Google colab (Pro)上でPythonコードを使っています。

手元のサーバーではPythonを使ってmultiprocessingやmultithreadingによる並列計算もできます。
Google colabを使用して、並列計算をしたいと考えています。

Google colabは頻繁に使用規約が変更されるため、自分なりに調べてはしましたが、いまいち把握できていません。
皆様のcolabで並列計算したときの経験を教えていただけると幸いです。

現状:
最大4 sessions(3GPU+1TPUを使った場合)で同時に計算は可能
各sessionでは2cpuが使える

例えば、

- 使用できるcpuの数を3以上にできるのか？
- 同時に使用できるCPUの最大数は？
- 計算時間の最大値は？（GPU使用では上限（3CPUを24時間回し続けた場合）があり、それを超えるとほぼ一日待機時間が発生します。）

など、情報・経験を共有していただけると幸いです。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: Colab Proもしくはその他の有料版の詳細を知りたい, という質問ですか？ (現在 Pro使っていないけど, ということですか？)

Comment: Colab Proを現在使用しています。Colab Pro上で一度に使用できる最大PCUの数などを知りたいです。その時にGPU使用と同じく制限がかかるのかどうかも知りたいです。Multithreadingで20workerは動くことを確認していますが、これは２CPU上だけの話なのか、>3CPUを使っているのかや、これを動かし続けた場合の制限・罰則などです。

Comment: 「20workerは動くことを確認」とは何を指してのことですか？何らかのパッケージのものなら質問にでもその旨 記したほうがよいでしょう。

Comment: 申し訳ないです。multithreadingを行うときに、いくつまで同時に並列で計算させたいかの指標としてWorker数を使う例が多いため、Workerを使ってしまいました。説明が足りませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab にはこの回答の時点では 3 つの有料プランがあるようです
[最適な Colab のプランを選択する](https://colab.research.google.com/signup/pricing?hl=ja) より

- Pay As You Go
- Colab Pro
- Colab Pro+

「Pay As You Go」についてはその下の「コンピューティング ユニットとは何ですか？」辺りを読むとよいかも

計算時間については

> 料金がかからないバージョンの Colab の場合、可用性と使用パターンによっては、ノートブックは最長で 12 時間動作します。Colab Pro と Pay As You Go では、コンピューティング ユニットの残量に応じてコンピューティングの可用性が高くなります。

「バックグラウンド実行」辺りにも説明があります

---

CPU コア数についての説明は上記ページには見当たらないけど, 次のようにして調べることが可能
(2行目以降は出力内容)

```bash
!cat /proc/cpuinfo
# processor : 0
# vendor_id : GenuineIntel
# cpu family    : 6
# model     : 79
# model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
# stepping  : 0
# microcode : 0xffffffff
# cpu MHz       : 2199.998
# cache size    : 56320 KB
# (中略)

# processor : 1
# vendor_id : GenuineIntel
# cpu family    : 6
# model     : 79
# model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
(…略…)
```

あるいは Pythonでは

```py
import psutil

mem = psutil.virtual_memory().total
free_mem = psutil.virtual_memory().available
print(mem, free_mem, f'{psutil.cpu_count()=}')
```

有料プラン使っていないので, Web調べた限りでは以下のようです
[CoLab Benchmarking](https://github.com/jeffheaton/present/blob/master/youtube/colab/colab_starting.ipynb) より

- Google CoLab Pro (High-RAM) (as of 2021-12-20)

  - **CPU Count: 4**
  - Memory: 25GB
- Google CoLab Pro+ (High-RAM) (as of 2021-12-20)

  - **CPU Count: 8**
  - Memory: 51GB

ただし Pythonには GIL があるので, マルチスレッドにしても性能は上がりません。以下のような対処が必要でしょう

- NumPy あるいはその他の (Pythonで実装されていない)演算であれば(スレッドであっても) GIL の影響は受けない
- [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/multiprocessing.html) などのプロセスベースの並列処理を行う

Comment: ありがとうございます！GPUと合わせてテストを行っておりました。CoLab proでは最大CPU は4なんですね。各セッションでCPUが２個使えましたので、もしかしたら最大２セッションかもです。やはりマルチスレッドでworkerの数を変えて計算時間を測定しましたが、ある程度（５－１０）以上では差がなくなるもしくは遅くなる現象が確認できました。最大CPUが律速なのか、GILなのかは特定していませんが、おかげ様で、１ セッションでMultithreadingを行う時のWorkerの数は5程度にとどめるのが良いとわかりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「CoLab proでは最大CPU は4なんですね。」…
"最大"が何を指してるのか不明だけど, Colab proで割り当てられるコア数は 4 のようです
ただ(回答に示した数値ではなく) 実際の環境で cpu_count を確認したほうがよいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。各セッションは2個づつCPUを使っているようですので、コア数が４であれば、2セッション同時に計算できることになると思いました。